How to access a nested dictionary with a tuple
I have a nested dictionary that I want to access via a tuple. How to do that?
    my_dict = {
            "1": { "a": "hi", "b": "bye" },
            "2": { "a": { "i": "howdy"}}
            }

# Way 1: Works
my_dict["1"]["b"] # prints "bye"
my_dict["2"]["a"]["i"] # prints "howdy"

# Way 2: Doesn't Work
my_dict[("1", "b")] # fails
my_dict(("2", "a", "i")) # fails


You'd have to subclass dict and overwrite __getitem__ to handle a tuples of keys. Alternately, you could just use the logic that you would overwrite __getitem__ with.

You can create a helper function (let's call it nested_get) to do that.
my_dict = {"1": {"a": "hi", "b": "bye"}, "2": {"a": {"i": "howdy"}}}

from functools import reduce


def nested_get(dictionary, keys):
    return reduce(lambda a, x: a[x], keys, dictionary)


assert nested_get(my_dict, ("1", "b")) == "bye"
assert nested_get(my_dict, ("2", "a", "i")) == "howdy"

